# Only one user can log in at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class declaration, `public abstract class CompanyHttpApplication : HttpApplication`

In the `CompanyHttpApplication` I have

```
public static CompanyHttpApplication Current
{
    get { return (CompanyHttpApplication)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance; }
}
```

and

```
public CompanyProfileInfo Profile
{
    get
    {
        return profile ?? (profile = ProfileManager
            .FindProfilesByUserName(ProfileAuthenticationOption.Authenticated,
                 User.Identity.Name).Cast<CompanyProfileInfo>().ToList().First());
    }

    private set { profile = value; }
}
```

Whenever I access the user:

```
CatapultHttpApplication.Current.Profile.UserName
```

it gets whoever is logged in last. I understand why (because it's in the application instead of the session), but I don't know how to change it. What can I do to change it so it uses the session instead of the application?

Comment: This is a an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  Instead of showing us what you've done, you need to tell us what you are trying to accomplish.  For example you might say, *How do I store values per user*, or *How do I access application variables through a user context*.

Comment: I wish I could explain better, but this is the best I can do. This isn't my program but I've been put in charge of it. The program was scheduled for deployment and now this error has cropped up. I have no idea why it's stored in application state anyway, nor do I have any experience in the area, and I'm trying to change as little code as possible because I can't make any sweeping design changes at this point in the game. I'm really just trying to leave it the way it is, but only using a session instead of an application state.

Comment: can you change the User.Identity.Name to Page.User.Identity.Name I am assuming that this is being done for asp.net webpage or applicatin